# If user logoff or their session times out how to end coldfusion session?

Tags: session, coldfusion, session-variables, session-cookies, logout

I have system that I built and for this project I used Ajax with JQuery. On back end I use ColdFusion and session management to handle users session variables. There is two situations (actually three if we consider closing the browser) where users session will end. One situation is if they click `Logout` then I have function that will clear `SESSION` scope with all information in it but session is not ended. Also `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` are still the same. Here is example of Logout function:

```
<cffunction name="LogOut" access="remote" output="yes" returnformat="JSON" hint="Used in session timeout handling">
    <cfset fnResults = structNew()>
    <cfset dt = createODBCDateTime(now())>

    <cfif structKeyExists(SESSION,"LoggedIn")>
        <cfset temp = structClear(SESSION)>
        <cfset fnResults.status = "200">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset fnResults.status = "400">
        <cfset fnResults.message = "Error!">
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn fnResults>
</cffunction>
```

Second scenario is once user session timeout. Here is example of that fucntion:

```
<cffunction name="timeoutSession" access="remote" output="yes" verifyclient="no" securejson="false">
    <cfset temp = structClear(SESSION)>
</cffunction>
```

Both of these functions will clear the session scope but not end the user session. I have used `cfdump` to check session scope once user logs out and CFID/CFTOKEN remains the same. I'm wondering how session cna be ended once they hit `LogOut` or `timeoutSession` function? Also should I rewrite the CFID and CFTOKEN every time user logs in the system? Here is example of my Application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cfset THIS.name = "MyApplication">
    <cfset THIS.sessionManagement = true>
    <cfset THIS.applicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 8, 0, 0)>
    <cfset THIS.sessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0)>
    <cfset THIS.requestTimeOut = "60">

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false">
        <cfset APPLICATION.appStarted = now()>
        <cfset APPLICATION.title = "My Application">
        <cfset APPLICATION.functions = CreateObject("component","udfs").init()>
        <cfset APPLICATION.sessionMinutes = 30>
        <cfreturn true>
    </cffunction>

    <!--- Runs when your session starts --->
    <cffunction  name="OnSessionStart" access="public" returntype="void" output="false">
        <!--- Clear the session. --->
        <cfset StructClear( SESSION ) />
        <!--- Set loggedin flag to false. --->
        <cfset SESSION.loggedin = false>

        <cfreturn />
    </cffunction>

    <!--- Run before the request is processed. --->
    <cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
        <cfargument name="thePage" type="string" required="true">
        <cfset REQUEST.appCode = 'SPA'>
        <cfset REQUEST.appName = 'Single Page Application'>
        <cfset var page = listLast(arguments.thePage,"/")>
        <!---<cfset onApplicationStart()>--->
        <cfif !listFindNoCase("Login.cfm,Authentication.cfc",page)>      
            <cfif !structKeyExists(SESSION, "loggedin") OR SESSION.loggedin EQ false>
                <cflocation url="Login.cfm" addToken="false">
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn true>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I'm not sure if session can be ended in `Application.cfc` or I have to do that in my `cffunctions`. Same for `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` what is the best place to set new values if user logs in again? If aynone have experience with this please let me know. I'm trying to prevent user to use the same session and raise level of security in my SPA.

Comment: This will give you some insight.  https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1131-ask-ben-ending-coldfusion-session-when-user-closes-browser.htm

Comment: @Dan Bracuk I saw that post and seems that is the way to create new session scope. Also I just looked over in cf document and there is function sessionInvalidate(). I have tested and seems that cfid and cftoken are reset if I use this on logout and sessiontimeout. Unfortunately there is not much resource on that. I'm wondering if this will end actual session?

Comment: `sessionInvalidate()` might be what you want but understand what it does (and what it doesn't). Good explanation here - [End active session on server](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2308718). Documentation here - [SessionInvalidate](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/sessioninvalidate.html) Note that it states: _The sessionInvalidate() method does not invalidate the underlying JEE session._

Comment: And you should probably look into `SessionRotate` when the session is started. Documentation here - [SessionRotate](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/sessionrotate.html). And of course it's caveat: _Does not rotate jsessionid when JEE sessions are enabled. This only works with ColdFusion sessions (CFID, CFTOKEN)._

Comment: @Miguel-F I read the answer from the Adobe forum that you shared above. Still not sure about statements they mentioned. I don't think that will be a good practice to keep session open once user logout from the system. In my opinion that is a security issue. Also if I use sessonInvalidate() and if J2EE session is still running would that be a problem? I'm not sure how that affects CF session?

Comment: I'm not sure how that affects the CF session either. There is not one simple answer to your question.  It's complicated (and I am no expert either).  If you want to learn more read [Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) for a start

Comment: Are you using J2EE Sessions or CF Sessions? If no J2EE, `sessionInvalidate()` and `sessionRotate()` will be fine.

Comment: @Shawn I do not use J2EE on my server but the other time does use this in their system. They mentioned is more secure. I'm not sure how and it's really confusing. If I turn on J2EE how that will affect ending session? Can I still use sessionInvalidate() ? Or I need another method to end J2EE?

Comment: J2EE sessions, I believe, are controlled through the JVM, so `sessionInvalidate()` (and `sessionRotate()`) won't do anything to it. Those only work on CF sessions.